# Jenkins Build with multiple commits

Tags: jenkins

Generally jenkins builds the code with the latest commit.Suppose in a build multiple commits have taken place.What I want is the list of commits that have been incorporated in the build.

Does anyone have a solution for this??

Comment: I think you already have that out of the box. Please elaborate, I guess I might miss something

Comment: Suppose in build no.1, I have only one commit with the appropriate msg. Now in build no.2, more than 1 commit has happened.....now Jenkins will build the code but display only the latest commit msg........I want to know the commits that have happened on the new build and display the commit messages for the same....

Comment: Which version control system are you using? In Subversion for instance you have exactly the behaviour you would like to have.

Comment: I'm using git here...

Answer (score 0):

If you press `changes` in a job, you should get a list of all the commits that are new for each build of that job.